# Is there AutoCloseable like class that doesn't throw Exception

Tags: java, autocloseable

Does any major Java library offer a `AutoCloseable` like interface for which close method doesn't throw exception?
My close implementation is very simple and I'd like to avoid the boilerplate of catching the exception

Answer (score 10):

An object *must* be a [`java.lang.AutoCloseable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html) in order to use it as a resource in a *try-with-resources* statement. But you can remove the `throws` clause from your implementation if it doesn't throw a checked exception.

For instance, if you have:

```java
public class MyResource implements AutoCloseable {

    @Override
    public void close() {
        // perform cleanup
    }
}
```

Then the following will compile:

```java
public void foo() {
    try (MyResource res = new MyResource()) {
        // use 'res'
    }
}
```

Without needing a `catch` block.

If you want, you can abstract this out into an [interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_(Java)).

```java
public interface MyCloseable extends AutoCloseable {

    @Override
    void close();
}
```

Note you can instead make the exception more specific if needed. The [`java.io.Closeable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/io/Closeable.html) interface inherits from `AutoCloseable` but changes the exception type to [`IOException`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/io/IOException.html).